# HTML 5 - input type text getting its value in real time

Tags: javascript, html, forms, onsubmit

I have a specific problem with getting the value of an input element of a html page, and print it in a paragraph on page.

Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
        function TakeValue()
        {
            var xs = document.getElementById("text").value;
            var p = document.getElementById("para");
            p.textContent = String(xs);
            document.body.appendChild(p);
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form onsubmit="TakeValue()" method="get" action="">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="click">
        <input type="number" name="value" id="text">
    </form>
    <p id="para">abs</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I press submit, for a moment the text content of the paragraph is changed,  but after it comes back to its initial value. I want that paragraph to remain changed after pressing submit.

I know this could be done without using a html form, but I actually want to find out if the task could be done this way.

Comment: The form is being submitted, which causes the page to be reloaded. You could cancel the submit with `onsubmit="TakeValue(); return false"`, but it doesn't make sense to use a form if you're not going to submit it one way or another. By the way, you don't need to use `String()`, because `xs` already contains a string.

Comment: if you're not posting your form to a URL, don't use `action=""` and don't hook into `onsubmit`. Instead, use a <button> with an `onclick` handler and keep the form just `<form> .... </form>`: you clearly don't want the browser's built-in form submission

Comment: Also make sure you do `<button type="button">` otherwise it will act as a submit button when inside a form.

Comment: Oh, I see! Thank you very much!

Comment: If your question is answered by any of the replies than please accept a reply so that others won´t believe that your question is still unanswered. If you still have questions please elaborate and we will try to help.

Comment: Thank you for observation! I didn't know that I have to accept a reply. Have a nice day! @surfmuggle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may `return false` in the function (and return that on function call).  This isn't as clear as specifying `return false` after the function call (inside the `onsumbit=""`) which would probably be better for whomever is maintaining the code.

```js
function TakeValue() {
  var xs = document.getElementById("text").value;
  var p = document.getElementById("para");
 
  p.textContent = String(xs);
  document.body.appendChild(p);

  // perform FormValidation()
  // perform AJAXExecution()
  
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return TakeValue()" method="get" action="">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="click">
  <input type="number" name="value" id="text">
</form>
<p id="para">abs</p>
```

Comment: That's what I was trying to do. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oLrqEK

I changed.

```
 function TakeValue()
 {
      var xs = document.getElementById("text").value;
      var p = document.getElementById("para");
      p.textContent = String(xs);

       // Do you want to add a p or change the text
       // document.body.appendChild(p);

      return false;
  }
```

And this `<form onsubmit="TakeValue(); return false;" >`

Comment: I forgot to modify the code after trying some solutions. Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you want to add another paragraph or just change the the text of the existing p?

Comment: Nope, just change the paragraph, I mean every time I press submit.